# read single cell data from spread sheet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-docs

I have  spreadsheet, want to get(Read) one cell data, through following link, I can able to **add row, edit row, delete row, list of spreadsheets etc..** I can able to get all row information  but i **want to read only single cell data data**, any one can give me syntax for that

I am using Python and Google App Engine

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#AuthClientLogin

Thanks in advance

Kalyan

Answer (score 1):

[You didn't read far enough in the docs.](http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/docs/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#cellsQueryExample)

Modified ever so slightly from the linked example:

```
query = gdata.spreadsheet.service.CellQuery()
query['min-col'] = '1'
query['max-col'] = '1'
query['min-row'] = '2'
query['max-row'] = '2'
feed = gd_client.GetCellsFeed(key, wksht_id, query=query)
```

retrieves the data in the cell in column 1, row 2.

Comment: Hi Meredith,
                Thanks a lot , giving me answer for my query .. its working thank u verymuch

Regards
SK